# How to view youtube videos in 1080p in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, youtube

Since Firefox 40 it plays in HTML5 but can't choose 1080p... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article came up after a little googling:

http://news.softpedia.com/news/how-to-enable-1080p-youtube-support-in-firefox-40-for-linux-users-489491.shtml

> It turns out that not all the codecs are enabled by default, but that can be easily rectifiable. It's not clear why Mozilla feels that this feature is not matured enough to be used in the latest Firefox version, but apparently it still needs a lot of work.

The author recommends changing the following options in about:config

```
media.mediasource.enabled from false to true
media.mediasource.webm.enabled from false to true
media.mediasource.mp4.enabled from false to true
media.fragmented-mp4.use-blank-decoder from true to false
media.fragmented-mp4.* from false to true
Right click and create a new Bolean entry with the name "media.mediasource.ignore_codecs" and set it to true
```

I changed only the first two on my setup and it worked after restarting the browser.

Also I'm not sure of the implications or if it won't fry my laptop or break anything so use at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that before asking this question, but it works slowly... I reported the bug to firefox.